# Obj-C - Return 6 dates following today's date into NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the following code (NSDate) to get today's date, as well as the 6 days & dates that follow it. That said, how can I store this retrieved series of dates inside an NSMutableArray? I'm looking to display them inside a tableview.

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad { 

    NSMutableArray *weekdates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Add this line

    
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
      NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
      NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
      dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
      for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
      NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:today options:nil];
       //   NSLog(@"Next days are %@", nextDate);
         

    [weekdates addObject:nextDate];
          NSLog(@"The weekdates are %@", weekdates);
       
      }
    
 
}
```

**When I log weekdates, Console:**

```
2020-09-29 16:46:55.827948-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000"
)
2020-09-29 16:46:55.828346-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-09-30 23:46:55 +0000"
)
2020-09-29 16:46:55.828536-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-09-30 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-01 23:46:55 +0000"
)
2020-09-29 16:46:55.828720-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-09-30 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-01 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-02 23:46:55 +0000"
)
2020-09-29 16:46:55.828917-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-09-30 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-01 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-02 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-03 23:46:55 +0000"
)
2020-09-29 16:46:55.829126-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-09-30 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-01 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-02 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-03 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-04 23:46:55 +0000"
)
2020-09-29 16:46:55.829523-0700 [3151:2048064] The weekdates are (
    "2020-09-29 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-09-30 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-01 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-02 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-03 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-04 23:46:55 +0000",
    "2020-10-05 23:46:55 +0000"
)
```

**When I log nextDate, Console:**

```
2020-09-30 13:51:21.965954-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Wed Sep 30 13:51:21 2020
2020-09-30 13:51:21.966169-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Thu Oct  1 13:51:21 2020
2020-09-30 13:51:21.966230-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Fri Oct  2 13:51:21 2020
2020-09-30 13:51:21.966275-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Sat Oct  3 13:51:21 2020
2020-09-30 13:51:21.966365-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Sun Oct  4 13:51:21 2020
2020-09-30 13:51:21.966436-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Mon Oct  5 13:51:21 2020
2020-09-30 13:51:21.966495-0700 [3227:2185065] The weekdates are Tue Oct  6 13:51:21 2020
```

Comment: You can use [`addObject`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutablearray/1411274-addobject?language=objc) — are you having trouble with that? Your code sample doesn't include a NSMutableArray.

Comment: who said you cannot append an NSDate object to an NSMutableArray?

Comment: @jtbandes I thought so - when I use addObject to add dates to my mutablearray (_weekdates), the array comes back NULL, even though nextDate is populated with the 7 dates.

Comment: Note that you have a single NSLog statement in the code you posted: `NSLog(@"Next days are %@", nextDate)`. The string "Next days are" does not appear anywhere in your sample output. The string "The weekdates are" which **does** appear your sample output doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted. We can't tell you what is going on with your code when you don't show us that code. If you want help figuring out your test output, please update your question to show the actual code that generates that output.

Comment: See updated :) @DuncanC

Comment: I think you are seeing the difference between `description` and `debugDescription`. To display the dates inside a table view, you should use neither of those — instead use NSDateFormatter. I think we've strayed a bit far from the original question, so I would recommend not further editing this question, but accepting an answer here and just posting a new question if you have trouble with NSDateFormatter. It looks like you have accomplished the original goal of this question, which was to get the dates into an array.

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: You said: "...when I use addObject to add dates to my mutablearray (_weekdates), the array comes back NULL, even though nextDate is populated with the 7 dates."

What do you mean "the array comes back null?" Your code creates a local variable weekdates, which you populate with dates, and then discard. Your function does not return anything. There is no array to "come back null." Do you have a variable weekdates in your view controller that you are trying to populate? Because your code is not doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm pretty out of practice with Objective-C. Let's see if I can get this right:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
NSMutableArray *dates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Add this line
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
    NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay 
        value:i 
        toDate:today 
        options:nil];
    NSLog(@"Next days are %@", nextDate);
    [dates addObject: nextDate];    //And this line too.
}
//The dates array should now contain all of your dates.
```

### Edit:

Since you you crate a date formatter, you should use it!

Here is an improved version of your method that logs your dates using your date formatter:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; //This is REALLY important. Always call super viewDidLoad
    NSMutableArray *weekdates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //Add this line

    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"ddMMM";
    for (UInt16 i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        NSDate *nextDate = [calendar dateByAddingUnit:NSCalendarUnitDay value:i toDate:today options: 0];
        [weekdates addObject:nextDate];
        NSLog(@"Weekdate %d = %@", i+1, [dateFormatter stringFromDate: nextDate]);
    }
}
```

Here is what some sample output from that code looks like:

```
Weekdate 1 = 01Oct
Weekdate 2 = 02Oct
Weekdate 3 = 03Oct
Weekdate 4 = 04Oct
Weekdate 5 = 05Oct
Weekdate 6 = 06Oct
Weekdate 7 = 07Oct
```

(after stripping away the timestamps and other noise from the `NSlog()` function)

Comment: See my code edit above. This works, but it spits out each series of dates 7 times (all of the dates up to each date each time?) Ha ha! I just want each of the 7 dates list one time, and preferably with Day, Date, Year format.

Comment: The 7 dates are added to the `dates` array. You see the series 7 times because of the NSLog statement.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer to log your dates cleanly using the date formatter you created in your code. Take a look.

Comment: (Up-votes gratefully accepted). Did you see my comment on your question, in response to your statement that "...the array comes back NULL..."

Answer (score 0):

```
    NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:today];
    NSLog(dateString);
    
    NSMutableArray *allDates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.day = 1;
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        NSDate *nextDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate: currentDate options:0];
        [allDates addObject: nextDate];
        currentDate = nextDate;
        
        NSString *dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate: nextDate];
        NSLog(dateString);
    }
```

Comment: Why rewrite the OPs date formatter and her other code? Her approach of using `[calendar dateByAddingUnit:value:toDate:options]` seems fine. Your approach of using `[calendar dateByAddingComponents:toDate:options:]` seems fine as well, but why rewrite the OPs code?

Comment: See my code edit above (and the console data). This works, but it spits out each series of dates 7 times (all of the dates up to each date each time?) Ha ha! I just want each of the 7 dates list one time, and preferably with Day, Date, Year format.

Comment: The question kept getting edited ever since I posted my code. I didn't mean to repeat any code.

Comment: The 7 dates are added to the `allDates` array. You see the series 7 times because of the NSLog statement.

Comment: @jtbandes See question update. I want what I see when I log in nextDate to appear when I log 'weekdates'. Not sure why but when I add nextDate to weekdates, it changes the format completely?